# Suppress all make output except for errors and warnings

Tags: makefile

I have a makefile which builds a project composed of many files which all need to be built.

To make matters more complicated, I have a number of included directories in each call to gcc (so each call to gcc looks long on the command line).

I'd like to suppress all output except for errors and warnings (so that I can actually see them when make runs!)

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: @pst you are the man! Please post as an answer so I can mark as accepted. BTW... do you know if there is any way I can do this from the makefile so that the `make` command remains straight-forward?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Depending on how "errors and warnings" are reported ...

```
make > /dev/null
```

That will redirect all STDOUT (Standard Output) from the make command (and thus all sub-processes it spawns) to the endless bit-bucket of nothingness. This may be too greedy though, as some programs use STDOUT (and not STDERR) to report warnings.

I do not know of a way globally change STDOUT of all sub-processes from within the context of the Makefile itself.

Happy coding.

Comment: Thank you!! That's just what I needed. (Works perfectly with gcc)

Answer (score 34):

`make -s` should do what you're after a bit more neatly. I don't know of a way to force it on the makefiles, but the GNU manual might have one.

Failing that you could check the Linux kernel build system, since that seems to automatically hide stdout.

Comment: That still prints "Making all in crypto" etc for me :/. Using GNU Make 4.1

Answer (score 32):

By adding a "@" to the front of a command,  the command line string is suppressed
e.g.
from

```
$(addprefix $(OUTPUT_PATH)/,$(C_OBJ)): $(OUTPUT_PATH)/%.o: %.c
        $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@
```

to

```
$(addprefix $(OUTPUT_PATH)/,$(C_OBJ)): $(OUTPUT_PATH)/%.o: %.c
        @$(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@
```

will take

```
make[1]: Entering directory `.../libraries/libgcdc/build'
/home/crowe/arm-tools/gcc-arm-none-eabi-4_6-2012q2/bin/arm-none-eabi-gcc -c -Wall -Wchar-subscripts -Wcomment -Wformat=2 -Wimplicit-int -Werror-implicit-function-declaration -Wmain -Wparentheses -Wsequence-point -Wreturn-type -Wswitch -Wtrigraphs -Wunused -Wuninitialized -Wunknown-pragmas -Wfloat-equal -Wundef -Wshadow -Wpointer-arith -Wbad-function-cast -Wwrite-strings -Wsign-compare -Waggregate-return -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes -Wmissing-declarations -Wformat -Wmissing-format-attribute -Wno-deprecated-declarations -Wpacked -Wredundant-decls -Wnested-externs -Winline -Wlong-long -Wunreachable-code -Wcast-align --param max-inline-insns-single=500 -mcpu=cortex-m3 -mthumb -mlong-calls -ffunction-sections -g -O0 -D DEBUG -I.. -I../include -I../../libchip_sam3s -I../../libboard_arm_demo -I../../libboard_generic -I../../libusb/include -Dsam3s4 -DTRACE_LEVEL=5 -Dprintf=iprintf ../source/hid_callbacks.c -o debug_sam3s_svn2/hid_callbacks.o
make[1]: Leaving directory ` .../libraries/libgcdc/build'
```

to

```
make[1]: Entering directory `.../libraries/libgcdc/build'
make[1]: Leaving directory `.../libraries/libgcdc/build'
```

Answer (score 28):

You can also force the `-s` option as suggested by PaulW directly in the Makefile. Just add:

```makefile
.SILENT:
```

Comment: 6 yrs later, this came to my rescue! Thanks Motine